# Connecting multiple different voltage servos to the same controller

Tags: rcservo

I am using the [Pololu Micro Serial Servo Controller](http://www.pololu.com/file/0J37/ssc03a_guide.pdf) connected to an Arduino and multiple other servos (4 total) to make a robot arm.  Two of the four servos require 4-6 volts, while the other 2 require 7-10 volts, so I am planning on powering all the servos separate from the Pololu.

I have the Arduino and Pololu connecting to each other correctly (flashing green led), but the servo(s) don't move when plugged in to the control pins.  All the servos work correctly when plugged into a servo-tester.

I think that this problem could be fixed by connecting the grounds of the servos to the ground of the Pololu, but would like advice because I am not sure if it will work, or will end up frying one of the parts (We already fried a pololu).

Would connecting the grounds of the batteries to the ground of the Pololu help, or damage the parts?

[image: Wiring Diagram], but I couldn't figure out how to show the micro serial servo controller.

Comment: A Fritzing diagram would be useful to see the servo power wiring setup. You don't have enough reputation to post an image yet (I think you need 10?), but if you upload it somewhere and link it, someone can edit the picture in for you.

Comment: I added an image, but it isn't displaying properly on my computer (probably because of the firewall).  I think it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You have a floating signal of servo ctrl, because they are not on the same common. 
Output from arduino (if not on the same common as servo) will be on the different potential level than input on servos. So servo will see it as a floating potential between his ground and his vcc potential.
(i hope you did understand what i wanted to say, its hard for me to explain it on English :) )

I guess your diagram is not connected like you have posted, because you have connected +5 and gnd from arduino to digital 3 and inputs from both servos are connected.

Comment: I'm using a pololu micro serial servo to convert the arduino's serial signal to the signals for the servo.  I couldn't find a Fritzing image that was close, so I put in a breadboard instead.  I just figured out why it wasn't working, and I'm going to post an answer now.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the servos by connecting the ground of the external batteries to the ground of the pololu and arduino circuit boards, then spent an hour to realize that a wire was loose.  :S